# How do I alter the scheme entry for the horizontal axis line color for graph hbar?

Tags: stata

I am writing a new scheme base off of `plotplain`. One thing I have not been able to affect is the color of the horizontal axis line when using `graph hbar`. Right now I have  `color axisline gs10` as the scheme entry. This works for all other graphs I have tried, but when using `graph hbar` it comes out as black. I have fiddled around with every scheme entry that was coded as black in `s2color` (the base), but nothing actually changes it. Any ideas?

Comment: It is a bit odd, but `help scheme_axes` points towards `color tickline colorstyle` to control the color of the axis line. Have you tried that?

Comment: I did, and it doesn't change it. I figured it out, though: The reason is that ``graph bar`` is not putting in an axis line, but an ``hline``. The way I was able to control it is with:|

``axisstyle bar_scale_horiz    horizontal_default     // y axis of graph hbar``
``axisstyle bar_scale_vert     vertical_default     // y axis of graph bar ``